# JQuery Selector on table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, selector

I want to add a border to my table using data from the first column, like this :

[image]

there is rowspan in this column.

Which selector should i use ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach to have the desired output:

This uses jQuery to compute the rows based on the rowspan attribute.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2104/12gyczg4/)

```
$('table.table td').each(function () {
    var rowspan = +$(this).attr('rowspan'),
    index = $(this).parent().index();
    if(rowspan) {
    // apply red top border to table row consisting of rowspan td 
        $('table.table tr:nth-child('+(index+1)+')').css('border-top', '2px solid red');

    // apply red bottom border to table row based on index and rowspan count 
    $('table.table tr:nth-child('+(index+rowspan)+')').css('border-bottom', '2px solid red');

    // for left and right borders, go through the rows from index upto the count of rowspan
    for(var i=index; i < index+rowspan; i++) {
        $('table.table tr:nth-child('+(i+1)+')').css('border-right', '2px solid red');
      $('table.table tr:nth-child('+(i+1)+')').css('border-left', '2px solid red');
    }
  }
});
```

Let me know if this link and approach works out for you.

Comment: I will try tomorrow. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have one option marking all "subrows" with a class (to avoid them to have a top border) using jquery...

CSS

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 1px solid red; }
table tr:not(.subrow) { border-top: 1px solid red; }
```

JQUERY

```
$('table td[rowspan]').each(function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    for (var i=1, l=parseInt($(this).attr('rowspan')); i<l; i++)
        $row = $row.next().addClass('subrow');
});
```

And a fiddle example... https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/oq433521/

I hope it helps